# The reverse of wp_insert_post

Tags: wp-insert-post

When you need to delete a post programmatically  what wp function do you use so that if takes care of the wp_term_relations too?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`wp_delete_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post).

```
<?php
$some_post_id = 1;
wp_delete_post($some_post_id);
```

The above will delete the post with ID `1` -- well, it will actually set it to a "trash" status.  You can delete the post for real by setting the second parameter of `wp_delete_post` to true.

```
<?php
$some_post_id = 1;
wp_delete_post($some_post_id, true); // really deletes the post
```